# The usage of Hbase Cell Version

Tags: hbase

There is a question stuck me long time,I'm confused about the Hbase cell version,I know how to set versions and get versions etc API operations,but I don't know why there is version concept,and how to use version.
Is there any good example to help me understand the cell version purpose?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Versions can be used to store multiple, but fixed number of values for a column.  Imagine that you want to store the time stamp for the user's last 10 logins.  You can have a column called "loginTime", and set max versions to 10 while defining table.  Now, all you need to do is update the value of column "loginTime" every time that user logs in, and HBase will, instead of overwriting the previous value of the column, push the previous value down the versions list and store the latest value on top.  It internally will store last 10 updates to this columns, and dropping the older entries. Imagine doing something like this in an RDBMS, you will end up deleting old entries explicitly.

You can use "Get" method to retrieve as many versions as you wish.

Another possible use case can be, say you are building something like a version control system, let's say for a Wiki page.  You could store older versions of the page as versions in the "pagecontent" column.